# How to generate a layer of different color over an image?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm doing a grid with several elements in the sidebar of a WordPress site.
Each element of the grid is an image with a label below.
My goal is to have an image change: 
the normal state of the image is to be green (#66be2c), then to the passage of mouse cursor will change it in the original image.
I tried using two physical images for the two states and overlaying them when needed. But this solution is very wasteful... load two different image files is not a good thing.

There's a way to achieve the same effect in a more efficient manner?

This is a part of my page code:

```
<td style="width: 150px; text-align: center;">
  <p style="color: #66be2c;">
    <img src="mydomain.com/aaa/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/GreenImage.png" style="width:50px; height:50px" onmouseover="this.src='mydomain.com/aaa/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/OriginalImage.png';" onmouseout="this.src='mydomain.com/aaa/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/GreenImage.png';">
  </p
  <p style="color: #66be2c;">.NET</p>
</td>
```

**SOLUTION:**

The correct way to do this is creating a Vector Image.

What you need is an image editor (such as Adobe Illustrator or others) and a C compiler (in particular two libraries for xslt)

These are two links that may be useful: [SVG-Stacking_Guide](https://hofmannsven.com/2013/laboratory/svg-stacking/) and  [GitHub-SVG-Stacking-Download](https://github.com/hofmannsven/SVG-Stacking)

I hope this can be of help to others who have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bad approach,

I'm not an expert in CSS or design but i think you should do :

```
<div class='overlay'></div>
  <img src="mydomain.com/aaa/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/OriginalImage.png" style="width:50px; height:50px">
</div>
```

And put a class in CSS like this :

```
.overlay { background-color: your_color; }
.overlay:hover { background-color: transparent; }
```

Comment: No problem, Wilson! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can overlay a `DIV` with a lesser opacity on to the image, and then register the hover such that the covering div fades away and the *real* image appears.

```
<div class='cover'></div>
<img id='your-image' />
```

The CSS for the image would be as such:

```
.cover{
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   opacity: .7;
   background: green;
   /* additional transition effects */
   -webkit-transitions: all .3s;
   -moz-transitions: all .3s;
   transitions: all .3s;
}

.cover:hover{
    opacity: 0;
}
```

***Note*** that the *covering* div and the image should be in the *same* containing `div` relative to each other.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `::before` selector to achieve this.  This would mean not using any extra markup, and no javascript either.  You'd really benefit from not using that inline css either.  Take a look at [CSS :: Before](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/)

**HTML:**

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
  <p>
    <img src="mydomain.com/aaa/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/GreenImage.png" class="image">
  </p
  <p>.NET</p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
td {
    width: 150px;
    text-align: center;
}

td p {
    color: #66be2c;
}

.image {
    width:50px; 
    height:50px;
    position: relative;
}

.image::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: green;
}

.image:hover::before{
    display: none;
}
```

Basically, this targets your image with a class of `.image` and puts a 50 x 50px box on top of it with a  green background.  When you then move your mouse over it, it gets rid of the box.

You can see this working in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yh9druhz/)

Comment: i tried your code but with that i can only set the background or other properties. The effect that I would get is this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yh9druhz/1/) but without using two physical image files

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question then, are you hoping to effect the colour of a pre-existing image?

Comment: No problem, maybe I just explain myself bad.
Anyway, I do not know if that is possible, or if there's another way to do it.
The example is the fiddle above

Comment: It depends on the your exact circumstances really, there are ways you could use fewer images but I don't really think it's necessary.  I would personally use CSS and have 2 images but with Javascript you can be more confident that very old browsers will be reliably compatible.

Comment: I saw that with two physical image the first load is very slow, then when the files are loaded into cache memory is normal. The problem is in the first load.
I don't know how to make it more efficient.
Do you think that doing by CSS is better?

Comment: Both methods still need to load both images so shouldn't have much of a difference on the overall loading speed.  How many images are you talking about here?  The alternative would be to only use one image for each one which would be set as the background, and then move the position of the background so that the other becomes visible.  This would half the amount of images but increase the size of each individual image.

Comment: Are several images and all different. i have a grid with all icons of development environments such as visual studio, qt, sql,.. for each there is a green image and on mouse over them change into original image